# How can I search for a string containing a colon?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, search

I'm trying to conduct a search for a specific class name (containing colons): e.g. search parameters `[perl] Class::Data` and am coming up empty:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[perl]%20class::data&tab=relevance
and
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[perl]%20class%3A%3Adata&tab=relevance
are both redirected to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl

Is there any way of conducting such a search?

**EDIT:**  I'm making this a feature request for the ability to search with colons. -Lance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to search for `[perl] "Class Data"` this will restrict to all terms with `Class` and `Data` as adjacent words - as colons are stripped out during analysis this should also match `Class::Data`, however it will also match `Class-Data` `Class Data` etc... - you're then going to have to search through the matches yourself (there are only 2 on StackOverflow)

Comment: I agree... however, it would be nice if the SO search engine recognized this and rewrote the search parameter, rather than allowing google to strip one of the search terms.

Answer (score 3):

The only search engine I know of that doesn't ignore special characters is [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/). It's a search engine designed for programmers, so it indexes programming-related sites and does not strip symbols away like other search engines.

Here are the results for your example search for [perl class::data](http://symbolhound.com/?q=perl%20class::data).

Full disclosure: I am a co-founder and developer of SymbolHound. I also posted it on [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stackoverflow-for-special-characters).

Comment: The first link is broken (it times out— *"The connection has timed out. The server at symbolhound.com is taking too long to respond."*). The same for the HTTPS version. It was still [alive in 2015](https://blog.kleeut.com/2015/08/symbol-hound-search-for-devs.html).

Comment: It appears it [was broken in April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).

Comment: (For some reason, comments can't be linked to on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/help), but it is near *"I have been a regular but not very frequent user for the last few years. It worked for me up until a few days ago."*)

Answer (score 2):

The [new search engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) handles this much better, we'll no longer direct and give some decent results for [[perl] Class::Data](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+Class%3A%3AData).  That being said, I think we can do even better on those results - I'll keep this example in mind as we tune.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it would seem that google strips colons from search terms.  At least, http://www.google.ca/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=136861#exceptions_punctuations does not list `:` as one of the exceptions, so it seems to be in the "ignored" class. :(

**Edit:** Note that it *strips the colons*, not stripping the search term entirely. It would at least be better to turn a search for `[perl] Class::Data` to `[perl] "Class Data"`, rather than to `[perl]`.

Comment: Jeez, even quoting it Google decides to discard the colons. Thanks, Google! Bing behaves the same way, too. Think you might be hosed. :(

Comment: Stripping all symbols is a standard text processing technique.

Comment: Don't bother with the codesearch recommended by @DanM. I assume it worked but it is no longer available.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com worked for me with "`Redis::Queue"`.

Answer (score -4):

Can you do it through Google?

If not, then the odds of us being able to do it are.. vanishingly slim.

Comment: Google searches for "class" and "data" rather than simply invalidating the entire "Class::Data" search token. I don't know if that's any better, but it's at least *something*.

Comment: +1 If Google can't do it, it must be impossible. :P

Comment: @Jeff, we're programmers, we can do anything, Google just doesn't have the incentive to modify it's search for the programmer niche, but SO should certainly have the motivation.  There's not much more frustrating as a programmer than not being able to search for symbols.

Comment: The worst *explanation* I've heard from Jeff...