# How do I search for syntax stuff like "==="?

Tags: support, status-completed, search, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to search for punctuation/special characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters)

I just did a search on `javascript ===` on StackOverflow, and was taken to the page with **all** questions tagged javascript. Not really what I was looking for...

I ended up typing my question in the "Ask Question" header field and hitting tab to bring up the search results. When I worded it as "What does === mean in javascript?" one of the first hits that were shown was a question on this, closed as a duplicate but with a link to a question that contained the answer I was looking for.

I doubt that searching for syntax is uncommon, and if the search box currently strips symbols like = that very much limits the search functionality on a site about code.

Am I missing some hidden search feature here, or does the search box need some improvement?

Comment: You are missing some discussion: [Is it possible to search for punctuation/special characters?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters)