# How do I search for "application/xml"?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search

When I try to search for "application/xml" it instead searches for "applicationxml".  How am I supposed to phrase this search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching for "application xml" (with quotes). It isn't exactly what you asked for, but it seems to be good enough. And probably (sadly): [Is it possible to search for punctuation/special characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters)

Comment: Unfortunately that matches way too many questions/answers with "application" - which is very generic, so the results don't help

Comment: @user147272 did you put it all in quotes -- `"application xml"`? Most of the results look to be for `application/xml`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, use Google Site Search as described in [search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search). [This query](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22application/xml%22&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com/questions) will search for `application/xml`

Comment: The slash in that query is treated as a wildcard (`^`) and returns the same results as `"application xml"`, `"application+xml"`, `"application xml"`, `"application#xml"`, etc. There's nothing special about Google Site Search here that makes it include punctuation.