# Search does not return any results for <%#

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, help-center

Search seems to be broken,

Search does not return any results for <%#

I looked at :

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching
```

But It did not help.

update: With more trial and error I turns out that if I do search like: "<%#"
Then I do get results.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching page says use quotes only for phrases, but  quotes are needed in this case also.

I would like to suggest to update the search help page. As It is the first location people will look when their search fails.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters

Comment: What did you expect it to show you?

Comment: @Cole [This](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%3C%25%23%22)

Comment: @GeorgeCummins 0_0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added a note about searching special characters to the help center page about searching, but please note that the search page itself has a comprehensive list of search operators - click the "advanced search tips" on the right-hand side.

Comment: The thing is, the "advanced search tips" doesn't say that if you want to search for symbols/special characters, you have to enclose them in double quotes.