# ':' not allowed in searches

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I search for a string containing a colon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32181/how-can-i-search-for-a-string-containing-a-colon)

I'm sorry if this question has already asked; I'm unable to search for it due to the very same bug I am reporting.

**:** is not allowed for some reason in searches. For example, if you search for **std::copy** you are redirected to a page that shows you the search option..

I can understand this may be because of advanced searches such as **user:1**, but can't you make the search work anyway if the string is not an advanced search (such as std::copy)?

Comment: Yep, December 7: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32181/

Comment: It actually isn't an exact duplicate, the other wasn't a feature request, though I'll make it one now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something a programming site should definitely let you do.