# Does the low-quality question filter take input from multiple sites?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have read up on some of the links about help vampires in meta, and I was wondering if the automatic filtering system that is used to stop sloppy questions and answers **takes it input from all the SE sites that are being used by a user?**

I know that I have asked some questions in a field that I am not familiar with after researching the problem myself, but when an answer is posted it could seem to others that my question was not researched due to the woeful nature of the question. This not being the case I wonder *if the work that I put into other SE sites to help in a field that I am more familiar with is taken into account when I ask a stupid question on another site?*

Comment: Is there a fake definition somewhere?

Comment: This is probably the best description http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Comment: Also, see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/164367

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...I was wondering if the automatic filtering system that is used to stop
>   sloppy questions and answers **takes it input from all the SE sites that
>   are being used by a user?**

As far as I know, the filters are per-site.

> ...I wonder *if the work that I put into other SE sites to help in a
>   field that I am more familiar with is taken into account when I ask a
>   stupid question on another site?*

I don't think this is a good idea.  Each site is a completely separate community.  While there are some general guidelines regarding question-quality and general on-topicness that span all the SE sites, I think this separation is important.

My reputation on Stack Overflow should not allow me to bypass any quality filters on [Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/); that would be unfair to that community, forcing them to "clean up" my low-quality contributions (because trust me, any contribution I made to a cooking site *would* be awful).

The main thing is this: even if *you* have good intentions with this thought, there is far too much possibility for abuse of this type of cross-site privilege.

Answer (score 9):

Asking a question about a field you're unfamiliar with doesn't make you a help vampire. Asking a question without thinking first (poor grammar and spelling, burying the lede, overly generic title, bad tags, no code for a code problem, no "what have you tried") is getting you on the road to HV, but at that point you're still just someone who asked a bad question once.

To qualify for HV you have to keep going. Don't edit your question no matter how many comments you get that ask for more detail or make it clear you were misunderstood. Reply in comments or answers instead, or ignore them. Don't respond to answers either: don't vote them up or down, don't comment on them, don't interact. After a while, just ask another question. Maybe it's the same question reworded, maybe it's a followon question, who can tell? If you have an answer to your first (or everyone's misunderstood it, whatever) go ahead and delete it, since a help vampire doesn't even consider the possibility of helping some future stranger. But refer (vaguely) to it in your new questions. Assume we have all learned your situation and choose to remember it, so don't explain any background. Continue to ignore comments and answers, or possibly escalate to arguing in the comments and answers. Get a friend to post an answer that rebukes others for not providing good enough answers yet. Repeat. And Repeat. And Repeat.

If you are doing that on another site, I would support the software keeping you out of all the sites. But my guess is that it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Another point:

You have 10 answers (and 0 questions) on [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/5918/unecs).

**Help vampires don't do that.**

So you might be a poor question asker (you probably aren't, poor askers don't worry about their question quality as much in general), but definitely not a help vampire.

I have now looked at some of your questions on Stack Overflow, they are okay. You don't need to worry about being considered a help vampire.