# What *is* the vampire problem?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

We have a [vampire](/questions/tagged/vampire) tag, which has no description. What types of questions is this tag meant to be used for?

Comment: It's for: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick look at some of the tagged questions yields some relevant information:

[The Help Vampire problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/185714)

http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Also, it's always good to discuss protecting the community from those who insist on taking unwanted blood samples.

[Somewhat relevant](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aclS1pGHp8o)