# When does a question on stackoverflow cross over from a learning experience to a free consultation?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, answers

It's one thing to ask a question on stackoverflow to learn to solve a problem or figure out a solution.  It's another thing to get some free consultation.  Where does one draw the line?  Are there any rules of thumb?

Something I ran into recently was when a very specific question was asked (with an input data sample and specifics about field positions etc).  A fully working solution (source code) was provided in an answer.  The scope of the problem was then increased.  Now, the questioner wanted an explanation and code comments on the code.  Does one draw the line at this point?

In general, any thoughts about whether such behavior is to be encouraged or discouraged?

Comment: Should be strongly discouraged.  Period.  There are plenty out there who would start off with a `Hello World` program and extend it to a working compiler.

Comment: See [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @DavidRobinson The last line in the accepted answer is wonderful: `Eventually, the time between check ups increases to the point where we both give up.`

Comment: Also see [The Help Vampire problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Comment: It crosses the line in about [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/238586).

Answer (score 2):

#### Code only answer

A code only answer ultimately doesn't answer the question, but fulfils a specification. If questions are always answered with just code the answer is very much of the ["give a man a fish"](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/give-a-man-a-fish.html) variety rather than "teach a man to fish" and will lock people into always asking questions because they do not understand the answers they receive; they just copy and paste the code. In other words; a code answer that is above trivially simple should always include an explanation of why/how the code works and it is perfectly reasonable to ask for an explanation to be added

#### Should the question be answered at all

Without seeing the question in question it is impossible to say but if it is simply a request for code fulfilling some job then it fails

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of
> the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't
> work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question
> checklist

and should be closed as such.