# Should there be a flag condition for people "changing the goalposts" on questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

I have an issue with the behavior of some users on Stack Overflow. A couple of times now I have found that when answering a question, (and often after a long stream of "That didn't work") I find that the person asking goes back and edits a question, adding some **new** error that has occurred that was not related to the original problem.

By this, I fairly mean, that in asking the question an answer was given that allowed the person to "move on", but then they are making everything about the **new** issue.

My general feelings are that it is good practice to accept the answer you were given, realize you have a new issue, and move on to a new question. But as said, some people are "Changing the goal posts" and making their question about something entirely different.

Should there be a review process for this? My thoughts are that this type of action should be discouraged in some way.

And I **do** mean **actively** discouraged as opposed to different approaches to *dealing* with the OP being a little bit difficult. Should this be a **feature** with perhaps a **reputation consequence** for serial offenders.

Comment: Strongly related: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) [The Help Vampire problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby very good. Different terminolgy but worthwhile material

Comment: The worst part is that sometimes some random user reads the question after the edit and downvotes your answer because it doesn't answer the question's edit (which you haven't read yet).

Comment: @Bakuriu I read that response from the related post. Yes that is a problem. But the specific thing I'm bounding around is should there be a moderator feature to do something to actively discourage the **worst** offenders. I've met a few who could do with having their own reputation being stripped for this serial behavior.