# How best to deal with users who cannot generalize

Tags: discussion

I've not been able to locate any current topics on this.

What is the best way, overall, to deal with a user who seems unable to generalize? they ask for help with a problem where they need to add 1+2. Then (having obtained an answer), they ask a follow up question where they ask how to add 1+3. Then, separately, they ask for help with solving 2+1, and possibly another question about solving 3+1.

This isn't, specifically, involved with commutativity - it's more that the person seems to not be willing, or not able, to apply the specific answers<sup>1</sup> given in a more general way.

What should we do? Continue to answer? Mark as duplicates? Encourage them to edit their original question? (I've tried the latter, but not with much success)

---

<sup>1</sup>For the sake of discussion, assume that the answers are generally applicable.

Comment: Related: [The Help Vampire problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Comment: Editing is just going to turn it into a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: I would mark as duplicate and add a comment as to why you did so.  If it's really not a unique question, then in my book it's a dupe.  Especially if it came from the same OP.

Comment: Some people are just hopeless.  At some point you need to make the decision to stop wasting your time trying to teach the same person the same thing for the 5th time and just ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

Being direct and not negative is a good approach.

Refer them to the other answer and explain the transitive properties of the answers.  They may not understand that it is possible to generalize.

Abstraction is a hard concept for some people.  Being direct and positive is also hard.

Being an excellent communicator is something we can all try to improve upon ... no matter what our other expertise may be.

Or ... some people are just thick and cannot get it! (<-- this is example of direct+negative which is what comes to mind initially for many of us).

Good luck in improving on the communication.  It is key to life on so many levels and is hard to do.