# Badge suggestion: Editing your own answer after it is accepted

Tags: feature-request, edits, accepted-answer, badge-request

I'm not suggesting that this is a major problem that needs to be addressed, but the thought process does cross my mind sometimes, and I have certainly seen many examples of it:

After someone accepts my answer, I don't have as much incentive to improve it anymore, to address follow up questions in comments or clarify.  This is especially true when the answer was recently posted or edited, because it is already closer to the top of the activity list.

Perhaps there should be a badge for editing your own answer after it was accepted.  It could be something like:

Decent - Edited 1 answer after it was accepted
 Noble - Edited 20 answers after they were accepted
 Gallant - Edited 100 answers after they were accepted

Or whatever the names and numbers would be.

Perhaps another parameter, editing within X hours/days of being accepted, could be added.

(Decent as in a decent human being, not as in so-so.)

**Encouraged Behavior:**

The encouraged behavior would be to continue improving your answer, beyond what is strictly necessary to answer the question, after it has been accepted.  This would include fixing typos and adding sources/documentation to the answer, or answering follow up questions such as questions about special cases.  Many people move on after the answer is accepted, since it can't get *more* accepted, and people don't pay as much attention to questions with accepted answers.  Those who are *gasp* motivated by reputation often abandon ship at this point.

This would not encourage help vampires, as only one edit per answer would contribute to the badge.

Comment: Not sure what behaviour this promotes though; keeping your answers up-to-date is already needed to avoid downvotes in the future..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Promotes answering follow-up questions that aren't necessarily essential to answering the OP.  Encourages going the extra mile.

Comment: But we want to discourage help vampires.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't know what that term refers to. I'll just explain what I'm referring to.  When someone comments on your answer something like "Interesting.  Is that also true about broccoli?" (in the case where it is tangentially relevant to the original question and wouldn't be out of place in the answer itself.  OK, examples are hard to make up on the spot.)

Comment: See [The Help Vampire problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665) and [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478). Users that continue to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK let me try again, to make it simpler and clearer.  Let's say someone asks a general question, it gets answered and accepted, and someone (the OP or someone else) asks about a special case in the comments.  This is very relevant to the post, but is not strictly necessary to make his answer a good answer.  This would encourage going the extra mile to improve his post.  I don't think that has anything to do with help vampires.

Comment: Sure, but that is *hard to measure*. How is this distinguished from correcting a spelling error or adding in a documentation link? I do this *all the time* with my answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure if adding documentation shouldn't be encouraged behavior also.  Correcting spelling errors: a) that is also an improvement someone might not bother to make once their answer was accepted and b) it could be mitigated with my time-limit suggestion to limit the period to the one most likely to have the follow-up questions.

Comment: I much rather see people keep their answer ship-shape over time than in the short run. I'm still not quite seeing how this would promote behaviour we don't otherwise see enough of.

Comment: The accept tick is certainly never the end of the road for *me*. How much data do you have on accepted answers being less likely to be edited later on?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't have data, just observations.  I've noticed plenty of times when an accepted answer has a hanging question, as the answer poster moved on once his answer was accepted.  If only everyone was as intrinsically motivated as you, we probably wouldn't need _any_ badges!  But I can think of specific users for whom this is a pattern of behavior.  Especially on smaller sites, where questions aren't getting hundreds or even 10's of views after they have an accepted answer.

Comment: I can't help but feel that this would just result in people making trivial and unnecessary edits to their accepted answers just for the sake of one more shiny gold badge. As we have no way of automatically judging the quality of an edit, I can't see how that kind of behaviour could be prevented.

Comment: @JonK are you troubled by [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/248/illuminator) or [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/copy-editor) or [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/157/archaeologist), none of which seem to have any safeguards and no one has been complaining?

Comment: Illuminator yes, I don't understand why there was a need for it, and I feel that it could encourage answering poor questions just so that you can then go and edit them later for some badge credit. The others less so because we do at least have the suggested edit queue, so it's at least possible that a number of those contributory edits will be peer reviewed. There are no such safeguards in place when you're editing your own posts.